# What more I need to implement a "read more" feature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to implement a "read more" feature when I'm displaying content. I want to cut off the text either at 6 lines or by number of words (but prefer by lines, unless you have different advice).

I'm guessing I will have to use javascript for this and calculate the text cutoff somehow. But I'm not quite sure what I should be doing, and if there's any calculation or other steps to do on the php end. Can someone give me some advice? Are there jquery plugins that could help with this?

Comment: it is much easier to use a character limit than a line limit, considering that line height and width are variable with typeface and column size. Both are traditionally user configurable in web applications, and browsers can and will override type size. these thing complicate what "number of lines" really means.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this: [Expander-Jquery-Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/).  And it's pretty cool :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)  with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function of php

Comment: Wordwrap will not shorten the text. it will wrap the text

Comment: @Stewie:with substr it can do the job

Comment: I see you edited your question, but what is the need of wordwrap for this question ? I don't think that presentation is the the question here, amount of data it.

Comment: @Stewie: if you read question again there is need of wordwrap

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PHP, make two variables and truncate the "teaser" text variable to desired length

`$teaser =substr($long_text, 0, 250); //250 chars`

So, you have two variables, `$teaser` and `$long_text`. Use them as you like. You can use javascript to show/hide it Or if you decide to use a link (to a whole article page). You can altogether ignore the `$long_text`.

Answer (score 0):

Say your content exists in a file, then you need to read 200 characters with it using php, then go ahead and read until you find a dot so that you know you have read until the end of the sentence. Then your "Read More" read can point to a page for example `yourpage.php?fullcontent=yes` and when the `full content` argument is given you read all the file.